# Ruby API for Google Voice

Tags: ruby, google-voice

Is there a ruby API/Gem for Google Voice that anyone could recommend?  I found this gem http://rubydoc.info/gems/google-voice/ but it appears to be half-baked and I haven't had much success using it.

For Python there appears to be some viable options but would prefer a ruby option.

The reason I am interested in this is I would like to write some scripts to automate tasks that I can't do using the web application e.g. archive all read messages etc.  If this is not possible in ruby right now I would like to know if anyone has had success with a different platform and Google Voice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant say this satisfies your need completely.

I found this through googling

https://github.com/bratta/googlevoiceapi

and this java based, may be u can use this if u go with `jruby`

http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/

I haven't tried any but that does not stop you from experimenting :)